# Как получить значения массива чекбоксов на Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

У меня есть несколько checkboxes в HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="5">
```

Как мне получить все значения в Angular JS?

Я пытался добавить для каждого input: `ng-model="type[]"` но это не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать ng-model с разными переменными, или с разными элементами массива, после чего отфильтровать этот массив, чтобы получить только отмеченные элементы.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну и за что минус?

Comment: Теперь действительно не за что